# Can I, by looking at scores from a game, decide how much luck and how much skill is involved?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

My wife and I play a lot of rummy against each other, and we keep a record of the score for each game, as well as the accumulated score. Since I have a substantial lead at his point, I claim that I'm a better rummy player than she is, while she argues that it's pure luck.

Most people agree that rummy is a game that combines luck and skill, but for many other games it can be hard to decide.

Assume we have the following list of scores from a game, but we know nothing about the game.

```
Round   :  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  | Sum  Avg Wins
Player A:  -   -   5   2   -   -  17   -   -   -  |  24  2.4   3
Player B: 12   3   -   -   8   4   -   5  17   4  |  53  5.3   7
```

Is it possible to examine the scores and decide how much luck/skill is involved? It seems reasonable to me that both the total points and number of wins are important, but are there also other factors?

Comment: Is it a typo that both players score points in game 8?

Comment: If we just look at the number of wins, we _definitely_ can't conclude anything from these data. Even in a fair game of pure chance between two people, more than 75% of all 10-game sequences will end up with a disparity of 6/4 or worse to one side or the other.

Comment: With a much much longer data collection, you might find good estimates for the averages of both players, as well as estimates baout other characteristics of the random distribution. For simplicity, let's only determine the variance. Then we can ask: Can we reasonably assume that the variance is the same? Can the difference in averages also be explained by random (that is: Do we reject the null hypothesis that the averages are equal)?

Comment: Typo in round 8. I'll fix it.

Comment: I understand that 10 games are not enough to decide with any degree of certainty, but the method applied should be similar if we had thousands of games, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest analysis is for the number of wins.
Let $n$ be the number of independent games, and $X$ be the number of wins for Player B.
Then under the null hypothesis that the players are equally likely
to win any one game, $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n, 1/2)$.

If B is in the lead with $x > n/2$ observed wins, we would reject the null hypothesis (and conclude
that B is more skillful), if $P(X \ge x)$ is remarkably small. Smaller
the 0.025 might be a reasonable criterion.

In your case, $n = 10$ and $P(X \ge 7) = 1 - P(X \le 6) = 0.1719,$
which is not remarkably small. (The computation in R statistical
software is shown below.)

```
1 - pbinom(6, 10, .5)
## 0.171875
```

If we had $x = 9$ then $P(X \ge x) = 0.0107,$ which might be persuasive
to you or a neutral party, but possibly not to your wife who starts
with a deeply held belief that rummy is a game of chance.

It is not the *proportion* of wins that governs the outcome. If
Player B had $x = 35$ observed wins in $n = 50$ games, then the
computation would be $P(X \ge 35) = 1 - P(X \le 34) = 0.0033,$
a persuasive result. So if you maintain your proportionate lead
for a larger number of games, then you have a good case that you are
more skillful.

If you want to look in a statistics textbook under 'one-sample
binomial test', you can find
a more-technical explanation. Also, perhaps something about a
normal approximation, which might make sense for $n = 50,$ but
not for as few as $n = 10$ games.

---

Using scores would require a knowledge of rummy that I do not have.
If the winner has score $12,$ does it make sense to say that the loser
has score $-12?$ If so, here is a formal statistical test.

I find it hard to believe that these scores are
normal, so I'm using a one-sample Wilcoxon ('signed-rank') test
of the hypothesis that the population median score is $0$ against the two
sided alternative that it is not. This test does not require normal data.

The results from R
statistical software are shown below. To be persuasive, one would need
the `P-value` to be less than about 0.05. (The warning message has to
do with the two 4's in the data, and the fact that the sample median is 4;
I investigated this and found that the exact P-value must be above 0.20.)

```
 y = c(12,3,-5,-2,8,4,-17,5,17,4)
 wilcox.test(y)


        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  y 
V = 39, p-value = 0.2613
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0 

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(y) : cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Again here, it is possible that data from more games with a continuing
difference between players would yield significant results.